# Syntax Error in Mysql Trigger with if condition

Tags: mysql

I want to update two table using trigger ,so I am running the below query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER project_document_trig AFTER INSERT ON object_metadata
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
   IF NEW.group like 'group1' THEN
       UPDATE documents as document
           SET document.projects_count = document.projects_count + 1
           WHERE document.id = NEW.value;
       UPDATE projects as project
           SET project.documents_count = project.documents_count + 1
           WHERE project.id = NEW.resource_id ;
   END IF
END
```

I am getting syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code and check:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER project_document_trig 
AFTER INSERT ON object_metadata 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
   IF NEW.group like 'group1' THEN
       UPDATE documents as document
           SET document.projects_count = document.projects_count + 1
           WHERE document.id = NEW.value;
       UPDATE projects as project
           SET project.documents_count = project.documents_count + 1
           WHERE project.id = NEW.resource_id ;
   END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

---

Alternatively You can use:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER project_document_trig 
AFTER INSERT ON object_metadata 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
   IF (EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM object_metadata WHERE NEW.group like 'group1'))
   THEN
       UPDATE documents as document
           SET document.projects_count = document.projects_count + 1
           WHERE document.id = NEW.value;
       UPDATE projects as project
           SET project.documents_count = project.documents_count + 1
           WHERE project.id = NEW.resource_id ;
   END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the semi-colon after the `END IF`

```
END IF;
```